# Reiterate only through the first 5 element using jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

does anybody know how to reiterate through only the first 5 elements using jQuery's `each`?

```
$(".kltat").each(function() {
   // Only do it for the first 5 elements of .kltat class
}
```

Comment: you could do a counter and just return after 5 or call `slice(0, 5)`.

Comment: `$(".kltat:lt(5)").each(function() { ...`

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`.

Furthermore, the same documentation says of the callback you give to `.each`:

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.

So try something like this:

```
$(".kltat").each(function(index, element) {
   // do something
   // ...
   return index < 4;
});
```

So after you execute the loop on the fifth time (`index` will equal 4), the loop will stop. Note that using this *n*-1 logic is needed because you execute the body of the loop before you evaluate the breaking condition.

```js
$(".kltat").each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).css('color', 'red');
  return index < 4;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="kltat">Item 1</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 2</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 3</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 4</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 5</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 6</li>
  <li class="kltat">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! How is it possible to launch some other function from the .filter function once it reaches 5? Like in the answer of SalmonKiller?

Comment: @deemeetree, that's a complication to the same question which calls for a different answer. You need to look at `.filter()` and selectors such as `lt` and `gt`

Comment: @deemeetree so you want to do **X** for items 1..4, **Y** for item 5, and then break? In that case I'd just use an `if` / `else` block (but without the counter variable), or possibly just use simple array manipulation–i.e. `Y(results[4])`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a counter such as this:

```
var counter = 1;
$(".kltat").each(function() {
   // Only do it for the first 5 elements of .kltat class
   if (counter==5) {
     return false;
   } else {
     counter++;
   }
}
```

or something of this sort.

Comment: You don't need a counter. The `each()` callback provides an index as its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".kltat").filter(function (i) { return i < 5; })
.each(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to launch some other function from the `.filter` function once it reaches 5? Like in the answer of SalmonKiller?

Comment: @deemeetree It's possible, but I wouldn't advise it. If you want that behavior it probably makes more sense semantically to go with SalmonKiller's approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".kltat").slice(0,5).each(function() {
   // Only do it for the first 5 elements of .kltat class
})
```

And without jquery:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.kltat')).slice(0,5).forEach(function (element) {
    doStuff(element)
})
```

Comment: The non-jQuery version could be simplified to `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.kltat'),0,5)…`